# Assigning Defined Name to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and am banging my head against the wall why it does not work.
When using the commented line with the range as $K10 it works fine when I assign a named range rngValidation it does not work. The defined name range of "ptrValidationCells" is set to $K10.

```
Sub FormatConditions_2()

    Dim rngToFormat As Range
    Dim rngValidation As Range

    Set rngToFormat = ActiveSheet.Range("inpInputCells")
    Set rngValidation = ActiveSheet.Range("ptrValidationCell")

'    rngToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$K10<>FALSE"

    rngToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=rngValidation <>FALSE"

        With rngToFormat.FormatConditions(2).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With rngToFormat.FormatConditions(2).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = False
            .Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormatConditions executes in the Workbook environment, not the VBA environment (if I can put it this way), so you need to use a named range and not a VBA variable.

Alternatively,

```
rngToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rngValidation.Address & "<>FALSE"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nearly correct.  You can use `Formula1:="=ptrValidationCell<>FALSE"`

Comment: Well spotted, Chris. I hadn't noticed that rngValidation was effectively a constant and therefore completely unnecessary in the subroutine as shown.

Comment: I have usd the alternative method as tis is part of a larger project. Your suggestion throws a Runtime Error 1004 the rngValidation.Address shows $K$1048575 when code run with F8 even though the Defined Name in the Workbook is $K10

Comment: OK got it to work using Chri's suggestion - Many thanks for assistance

Comment: I don't understand how the 48575 appears; it works fine for me. The main thing is that you've solved your problem.